# Unit testing to protect against production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

We recently had a bug go into production where we added `validates_presence_of` to a model, but that column was nil for any records created before the change, so any code that instantiated the model on old data was broken.

This seems to be in a class of bugs that can only be caught when tested against the production data.

Is there a way to create unit tests that protect against these types of issues?

Comment: Production database can hold all sorts of unanticipated data. I recommend copying production db to a staging env every once in a while. Also, not releasing directly to production. :)

Answer (score 0):

When talking about writing automated tests for unhappy paths or cases in your code (also called negative testing), you will end up writing tests for the things you *expect* to happen. Take your `validates_presence_of` situation, you can write *now* a test that validates the proper handling of the case where the column was nil, because you know now that it can happen. Writing these tests before issues arise is the tricky part, because you don't know you have to.

If you really want to prevent these cases before they happen, you could consider:

1. **Testing against real data:** get a hold of a realistic database and run functional tests and database consistency checks in it. Some things to consider with this approach:

   - If the database you are considering as reference has customer data, you'll probably want to anonimise it, for the sake of customer privacy.
   - This approach is hard to get right within the development loop, as it's costly to automate the set-up and orchestration. This strategy is more suitable for a one-off effort, say, before doing a massive migration or something like that.
   - As I pointed earlier, you will still write tests for the things you expect to happen, but given you are increasing your dataset, there is a higher likelihood to stumble upon something unexpected
2. **Exploratory testing:** I know you mentioned unit tests in your question, because you want to automate this process, but another good way to prevent these cases before they happen is to apply your full brain energy in coming up with unexpected but feasible scenarios, and manually test them to see if your code supports these scenarios or not (and if not, bug caught, patch and write a test to ensure the bug never sees the light).

An automated approach that might scale better would err on the side of **detection** instead. At some point we have to accept that software has bugs and software development is not a flawless process that prevents all of them. It's very likely that some of those bugs get into production, so let's minimise the impact they have.

We still want to write tests to catch as many issues we can before releasing, so that the ones that reach our users are rare and not dangerous. When this happens, good logging practices, log aggregators, good monitoring of errors and good alerting schemes will let us know immediately, and we'll be able to react before it affects more users or gets worse.

This path can get even more solid when [canary releases](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html) are executed, [anomaly detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaly_detection) patterns are applied on real time behavioral data and automated rollbacks are programmed the moment things start going wrong.